# Why program doesn't enter into the if statement when it should

Tags: c, system-calls

I'm trying to implement an 'ls' command that lists file and directories. I have set the incoming argument array to the following:

```
argv[0] = "./a.out"
argv[1] = "-l"
argv[2] = "test.c"
```

Here is my code (assume that the `main` function passes `argc` and `argv` to the function `I_AM_LS`):

```
#include "ls.h"

int I_AM_LS(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    // 'INCLUDING_HIDDEN_FILE' indicates program performs ls including hidden files
    // 'EXCLUDING_HIDDEN_FILE' indicates program performs ls excluding.
    int     hidden_flag     =   EXCLUDING_HIDDEN_FILE;
    int     detail_flag     =   SIMPLY;     // default option in ls.
    // 'IN_DETAIL' indicates program performs ls with additional information.
    // 'SIMPLY' indicates program performs ls without.
    char option;
    int i;
    DIR * dp;

    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "al")) != -1)
    {
        switch (option)
        {
            case 'a':
                hidden_flag     =   INCLUDING_HIDDEN_FILE;
                break;
            case 'l':
                detail_flag     =   IN_DETAIL;
                break;
            default: /* '?' */
                printf("invaild option.\n");
                return -1;
        }
    }


if( argv[optind] != NULL && argv[optind + 1] != NULL) // multiple argument
{
    ; // I have not finished the corresponding code yet.
}
else
{
    if( argv[optind] == NULL) // case 1
        I_REALLY_CALL_ls("./", hidden_flag, detail_flag);
    else
        I_REALLY_CALL_ls(argv[optind], hidden_flag, detail_flag);
}
    printf("optind %d %d\n", optind, argv[optind]);
    return 0;
}
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    I_AM_LS(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

After the initial parsing loop, the program doesn't enter into the if statement 'argv[optind] != NULL'. We know that `optind` is 2 and `argv[optind]` points to "test.c", not `NULL`, the same behaviour is seem in debug mode.

Are there any problems with passing argv and argc to the function I_AM_LS? What should I do?

Note : I'm working on Xcode on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( argv[optind] == NULL) // case 1
    I_REALLY_CALL_ls("./", hidden_flag, detail_flag);
else if( argv[optind] != NULL && argv[optind] != NULL)
{
    ; 
}
```

The condition in this `else if` is `argv[optind] != NULL`, evaluated twice for no good reason. So if the first condition doesn't hold, this one does, you do nothing (`;`), and

```
else if( argv[optind] != NULL)
{
    // single non-option arguemnt.
    I_REALLY_CALL_ls(argv[optind], hidden_flag, detail_flag);
}
```

is unreachable.

Comment: It was errata. My intention is the statement 'argv[optind] != NULL && argv[optind + 1]'. I think this indicates command line consist of multiple non-option argument. I have edited code. Can you check for my code? have any improvements?